# Javascript no me reconoce el evento click de un boton

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un botón para poder descargar una imagen de una galería. El boton aparece dentro de un modal. Para verificar que se está llamando correctamente al evento uso `Console.log("evento funcionando")`. El problema es que cuando hago click sobre el botón Download, dicho evento parece no estar funcionando ya que el mensaje directamente no aparece en la consola.

Este es el modal:

```js
const btnDownload = document.getElementById('#btnDownload');

    btnDownload.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log("evento funcionando");
    })
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
            <div class="slideshow">
                <button class="btn" id="btnDownload"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
                <span class="btn_cerrar">&times;</span>
                <div class="botones adelante">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-circle-outline"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="botones atras">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-left-circle-outline"></i>
                </div>
                <img src="" id="img_slideshow"/>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Ya usé este mismo metodo para mostrar el `Modal`, por lo que en teoría debería funcionar.

Algo mal tengo que tener acá, ya que ni con las soluciones que me dieron (las cuales agradezco muchisimo) pude resolverlo

Este es todo mi código:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        let imagenes = [
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Celular.jpg' },
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Taza.jpg' },
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Horno.jpg' },
            { img: '/imgAndroid/TV.jpg' },        
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Monitor.jpg' },
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Notebook.jpg' },
            { img: '/imgAndroid/PanelSolar.jpg' },                      
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Teclado.jpg' },
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Samsung.jpg' },
            { img: '/imgAndroid/Mouse.jpg' },
        ]
    
        let contador = 0;
        const contenedor = document.querySelector('.slideshow');
        const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
        const imagenesTd = document.querySelectorAll('.galeria img');
        const img_slideshow = document.querySelector('.slideshow img');   
        const btnDownload = document.getElementById('btnDownload');
    
        contenedor.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            let atras = contenedor.querySelector('.atras'),
                adelante = contenedor.querySelector('.adelante'),
                img = contenedor.querySelector('img'),
                tgt = event.target
            if (tgt == atras) {
                if (contador > 0) {
                    img.src = imagenes[contador - 1].img
                    contador--
                } else {
                    img.src = imagenes[imagenes.length - 1].img
                    contador = imagenes.length - 1
                }
            } else if (tgt == adelante) {
                if (contador < imagenes.length - 1) {
                    img.src = imagenes[contador + 1].img
                    contador++
                } else {
                    img.src = imagenes[0].img
                    contador = 0
                }
            }
        })
    
        Array.from(imagenesTd).forEach(img => {
            img.addEventListener('click', event => {
                const imagenSeleccionada = +event.target.dataset.imgMostrar
                img_slideshow.src = imagenes[imagenSeleccionada].img
                contador = imagenSeleccionada
                overlay.style.opacity = 1
                overlay.style.visibility = 'visible'
            })
        })
    
        document.querySelector('.btn_cerrar').addEventListener('click', () => {
            overlay.style.opacity = 0
            overlay.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        })    
    
        btnDownload.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log("evento funcionando");
        })
    })
```

```html
 <body>
        <div class="overlay">
                <div class="slideshow">
                    <button class="btn" id="btnDownload"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
                    <span class="btn_cerrar">&times;</span>
                    <div class="botones adelante">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-circle-outline"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="botones atras">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-left-circle-outline"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="" id="img_slideshow"/>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>CUIT / DNI</th>
                        <th>Número de remito</th>
                        <th>Número de pedido</th>
                        <th>Monto</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1111</td>
                        <td>1111</td>
                        <td>1111</td>
                        <td>$16167171</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <section class="galeria">
                <div class="columnaPedido">
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Celular.jpg" data-img-mostrar="0"/>
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Taza.jpg" data-img-mostrar="1"/>
                </div>
                <div class="columnaPedido">
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Horno.jpg" data-img-mostrar="2"/>
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/TV.jpg" data-img-mostrar="3"/>
                </div>
                <div class="columnaPedido">
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Monitor.jpg" data-img-mostrar="4"/>
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Notebook.jpg" data-img-mostrar="5"/>
                </div>
                <div class="columnaPedido">
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/PanelSolar.jpg" data-img-mostrar="6"/>
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Teclado.jpg" data-img-mostrar="7"/>
                </div>
                <div class="columnaPedido">
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Samsung.jpg" data-img-mostrar="8"/>
                    <img class="imgPedido" src="~/imgAndroid/Mouse.jpg" data-img-mostrar="9"/>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    
        <script src="~/js/main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Comment: La linea const btnDownload = document.getElementById('#btnDownload');

No debe llevar el # sino unicamente el nombre del Id

Comment: No, tampoco funciona sin el #

Comment: ¿El script está declarado después de que se carga el DOM (inherente al modal) en memoria?

Comment: @BilbitBolson he probado todo el código que proporcionaste y funciona correctamente, el evento es llamado. Utiliza las DevTools de tu navegador para revisar tu problema.

Comment: Mira que te puse tu código como snippet y funciona.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema es que al seleccionar el elemento por id debe ser así:

```
('#btnDownload') //incorrecto
('btnDownload') // forma correcta
```

Te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
const btnDownload = document.getElementById('btnDownload');

btnDownload.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    console.log("evento funcionando");
})
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="slideshow">
            <button class="btn" id="btnDownload"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
            <span class="btn_cerrar">&times;</span>
            <div class="botones adelante">
                <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-circle-outline"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="botones atras">
                <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-left-circle-outline"></i>
            </div>
            <img src="" id="img_slideshow"/>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

No mezcles jquery con js puro. El ID lo obtienes sin el `#` en ese método getElementById

```js
const btnDownload = document.getElementById('btnDownload');

    btnDownload.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        console.log("evento funcionando");
    })
```

```html
<div class="overlay">
            <div class="slideshow">
                <button class="btn" id="btnDownload"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
                <span class="btn_cerrar">&times;</span>
                <div class="botones adelante">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right-circle-outline"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="botones atras">
                    <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-left-circle-outline"></i>
                </div>
                <img src="" id="img_slideshow"/>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Voy a pasar todo mi Js porque algo no estoy haciendo bien